# How to compare grid rows and columns with user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Alright, so I have this code which basically will prompt the user to enter a number and then according to that number the user entered, they will be asked (Please enter a number between 1 and 4)* the number the user chose. Then, their input will be compared to see if there is any match in the grid (rows and columns). Let me show you an example:

- Please enter a number: **3**
- Please enter a number between 1 and 4: **2**
- Please enter a number between 1 and 4: **1**
- Please enter a number between 1 and 4: **2**

Here is your grid:
(3x3 grid filled, since user entered **3**, filled with random numbers)

```
 4  2  4
 3  1  1
 4  3  3
```

---

Here is a sample of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

double Atemp = 0;
double Utemp = 0;
double Working = 0;
double Total = 0;
char Answer = 'x';

int Umain;


void printGrid(int &Umain);

void fillIntArray(int array[], int size);
void reverseArray(int array[], int size);
void outputIntArray(int array[], int n);

void compareGrid(int &Atemp);

int main(){


    int maxNum = 2;
    int intArray[maxNum];


    cout << "Please Enter numbers between 1 and 12: ";
    cin >> Umain;


    do{
       if(Umain <=12){
        fillIntArray(intArray, maxNum);
        //outputIntArray(intArray, maxNum);
        printGrid(Umain);
       }
    }while (Answer == 'y');


    return 0;
}


void fillIntArray(int array[], int size){

    do{
    for (Utemp = Umain; Utemp > 0; Utemp--){
      cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 4: ";
      cin >> Atemp;
        if(Atemp <=4 && Atemp >=1){
            for (int i = Atemp; i < Atemp; i++);
            }else{
                cout << "Not within limit \n";
                }
            }
    }while (Answer == 'y');
}


void printGrid(int &Umain){

  cout<<endl;
    cout<<" ";
        int i=1,j;
        for(j = 0; j <= 4*Umain; j++){
            if(j%4==2){
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }

  cout<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= 2*Umain; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= 2*Umain; j++){
        if(i%2==0){
        if(j==0){
            cout<<" ";
        }
        if(j%2==0){
            cout<<" ";
        }else{
            cout<<"---";
        }
      }else{
        if(j%2==0){
            cout<<" | ";
        }else cout<< (rand()%4+1);
      }
    }
        if(i%2!=0){
            cout<<" ";
        }
    cout<<endl;
  }
  cout<<" ";

    for(j = 0, i = 1; j <= 4*Umain; j++){
        if(j%4==2){
            cout<< " ";
        }
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

void compareGrid(int &Atemp){

}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: *How to compare grid rows and columns* ?????? Its written, literally

Comment: grid rows and columns  => matrix. That's the correct term

Comment: And what do you mean by *"compare"*? Compare every element?

Comment: Compare the numbers the user entered with the numbers in the 2D array, is there a match or not, if they entered 2 3 2, is there the same numbers matched in order in the rows or columns in the 2D array?. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, variable size arrays are not a part of C++. This part is wrong:

```
int maxNum = 2;
int intArray[maxNum];
```

Fix it by adding `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int maxNum = 2;
int intArray[maxNum];
```

Secondly, this part in general doesn't make sense and the semicolon at the end is really suspicions:

```
for (int i = Atemp; i < Atemp; i++); // why?
```

And assuming you have collected the user inputs in an array called `Attempts` of size 3, and `intArray` is the matrix of size 3x3, here's how you might compare attempts to the rows/columns of the so-called 2D array:

```
bool Contains() {
    for (size_t iCol = 0; iCol != 3; ++iCol) {
        for (size_t iRow = 0; iRow != 3; ++iRow) {
            if(intArray[iCol][iRow] != Attempts[iRow]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Change places of `iCol` and `iRow` to check rows or columns